# ValueError: Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("total:0", shape=(), dtype=resource)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, flask

I built a three-layer neural network to predict the proper name of a column based on its contents. The model works fine on tensorflow 1.12; it's even deployed and working in production right now.

However, when we tried running the same service with tensorflow 1.13, it broke with the following error.

> 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2019 16:28:15] "[1m[35mPOST /999/qqq/upload_to_column_check HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 - Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997,
>   in **call**
>       return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985,
>   in wsgi_app
>       response = self.handle_exception(e)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540,
>   in handle_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line
>   33, in reraise
>       raise value   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982,
>   in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614,
>   in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517,
>   in handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line
>   33, in reraise
>       raise value   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612,
>   in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598,
>   in dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint   File "C:\Users\Matt
>   Casey\iqm\iqmpolisegments-datarecievers-columnnames\api_service.py",
>   line 231, in upload_then_columns
>       name_dict, conf = cp.predict_based_on_header_and_list(ColName, ColVals)   File "C:\Users\Matt
>   Casey\iqm\iqmpolisegments-datarecievers-columnnames\header_service_core.py",
>   line 299, in predict_based_on_header_and_list
>       lpreds = self.predict_based_on_list(initial, arr_only = True)   File "C:\Users\Matt
>   Casey\iqm\iqmpolisegments-datarecievers-columnnames\header_service_core.py",
>   line 237, in predict_based_on_list
>       preds = self.classifier.predict(vectorized)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1113, in predict
>       self, x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose, steps=steps)   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py",
>   line 251, in model_iteration
>       model.reset_metrics()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1119, in reset_metrics
>       m.reset_states()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py",
>   line 460, in reset_states
>       K.set_value(v, 0)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py",
>   line 2844, in set_value
>       assign_op = x.assign(assign_placeholder)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py",
>   line 917, in assign
>       self.handle, value_tensor, name=name)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_resource_variable_ops.py",
>   line 186, in assign_variable_op
>       "AssignVariableOp", resource=resource, value=value, name=name)   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 350, in _apply_op_helper
>       g = ops._get_graph_from_inputs(_Flatten(keywords.values()))   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 5713, in _get_graph_from_inputs
>       _assert_same_graph(original_graph_element, graph_element)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 5649, in _assert_same_graph
>       original_item)) ValueError: Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("total:0",
>   shape=(), dtype=resource).

I was unable to make sense of this. So, I pulled the object over into a Jupyter notebook for troubleshooting. Except, when I do, the error disappears and it works fine.

The following should be the relevant code:

```
def predict_based_on_list(self, initial, arr_only = False):
    """
    Initial:
        str in list form, values separated by '|'
        OR a list of strings. The strings should all be values from the
        same column of a spreadsheet

    returns:
        np.array, the output of the neural network with shape (1, len(headers)).
        Each entry in the array represents affinity for a particular column
        the higher the value, the closer the affinity.
    """
    conf_array = np.zeros((1, len(self.headers)))
    if type(initial) == str:
        vals = initial.split('|')
        print('in split', vals)
    else:
        vals = initial
        print('in = initial', vals)
    rows = len(vals)
    vectorized = [self.convert_val_to_metadata(val) for val in vals]
    vectorized = pd.DataFrame(vectorized)
    vectorized.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    vectorized = np.array(vectorized, dtype='float64')

    preds = self.classifier.predict(vectorized)

    avgs = preds.sum(axis=0) / len(vals)

    return avgs
```

If you have any brilliant ideas, I'd love to hear them. I'm baffled.

Comment: Without seeing the TF code it will be hard to tell anything.

Comment: What portion of the code are you looking for? My boss would probably be unhappy if I dumped the whole thing on here.